# mysql tables union and new column

Tags: mysql, union

Give two following tables,

phone table:

```
 PID   NAME
1001 iphone
1002 samsung
1003 sony
```

pc table:

```
 CID  NAME
1001 HP
1002 XPS
```

how can i get the result table?

```
  DID  TYPE NAME
 1001 PHONE iphone
 1002 PHONE samsung
 1003 PHONE sony
 1001 PC    HP
 1002 PC    XPS
```

I think this should use UNION, but how to deal with the TYPE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use UNION ALL if you want to duplicates result also, Otherwise you can use UNION to eliminate duplicate values.

Your query will be like this,

```
select pid as DID,'PHONE' as TYPE,name from phone
UNION all
select CID as DID,'PC' as TYPE,name from PC;
```

This will select all records from both tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PID AS DID, 'PHONE' AS TYPE, NAME FROM Phone
UNION ALL
SELECT CID AS DID, 'PC' AS TYPE, NAME FROM PC;
```

Comment: UNION will eliminate duplicate records.
For eg. 1001,1002 will be picked only once.

UNION ALL will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query :

```
select pid as DID,'PHONE' as TYPE, name from phone
UNION 
select cid as DID,'PC' as TYPE, name from PC;
```